# C#: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported

Tags: c#, build-error

In VS2017 I changed the framework for my project from 4.5.2 to 4.6.2 which is needed for the webview component but then I get this error:

> Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\pc\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Rosebud\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.4.6.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll' and 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\VS 2015 projects\dbtest\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.4.7.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

> 1>CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\pc\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Rosebud\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.6.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll' and 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\VS 2015 projects\dbtest\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.7.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

I looked at similar threads but didn't find an answer, the problem is those references are not in the reference folder. In the folder are only these two runtime references:

- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
- System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

So how do I remove the duplicates ?

EDIT:
The problem is that there are 2 folders with packages. The project is in a folder named "VS 2015" on my desktop and there's a packages folder in my solution: C:\Users\pc\Desktop\VS 2015 projects\dbtest\packages  which contains 2 runtime refs:

- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.7.0
- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.4.7.0

But there's also a packages folder in my documents folder: C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Rosebud\packages which contains

- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.6.0
- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.4.6.0

When I delete the packages from the second folder path I get the error that the packages are missing. When I delete the packages and the bin & obj from the first folder path he automatically restores the packages when I build the project but I get an error saying C:\Users\pc\Desktop\VS 2015 projects\dbtest\packages\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.10.0.22621.755\build\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.targets(4,5): error : Must use PackageReference
I tried "Migrate packages.config to PackageReference" but I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you updated all Nuget packages to the latest versions? Also, do a clean (from the `Build` menu in VS), then close VS, delete any `bin` and `obj` folders you can find, then restart VS and see if it helps.

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel Deleted the folders but didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try closing VS, deleting the whole `C:\Users\pc\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Rosebud\packages` folder, then restarting VS

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel Tried this too but then he says the package is missing.

Comment: Is this a nuget package? If so, then you should be able to restore it. Right-click the solution in Solution Explorer and choose "Restore Nuget packages"

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel The problem is that there are 2 folders with packages. The project is in a folder named "VS 2015" on my desktop and there's a packages folder in my solution: C:\Users\pc\Desktop\VS 2015 projects\dbtest\packages

Comment: I'm not clear about this. Please update your question, as this may be important information. Please give full and exact paths to both folders.

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel I edited my question, I couldn't type everything in my comment.

Comment: At this stage, I'm a bit lost. I would suggest creating a completely new solution, and copying your source files into it. See if that will compile. I know it's a pain, but it might save time in the long run

Comment: Do you have a packages.json somewhere in your project folder? Can you show its contents? Maybe also check your .csproj file for reference issues.

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel Yeah I know it's a mess, I don't know why vs2017 created that document folder. I'll create a new solution, thanks for the help.

Comment: @ewerspej I have a System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json package.

Comment: No, I meant a file called packages.json

Comment: Nope, don't have such package.

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel I finally solved it: I had to edit my csproj file and delete all folder paths that contained the document folder.

Comment: @IngmarHelsmoortel Excellent, glad you got sorted. Maybe you should add that as an answer, so other people can benefit

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it: I had to edit my csproj file and delete all folder paths that contained the document folder.